# Angular Material - Store checkbox status (checked or not)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I'm searching for a way to store checkbox values (if it was checked before or not). More specifically, I have this dialog:
[image]

If I click on one checkbox and then click Save, when I re-open the dialog, they are all unchecked again. They should stay checked if I have checked them before.

**dialog-settings.html**

```
    <h1 mat-dialog-title>Settings</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <section [formGroup]="dynamColumns">
    <ul>
      <mat-checkbox color="primary" formControlName="name">Name</mat-checkbox>
      <mat-checkbox color="primary" formControlName="telNum"
        >Telephone Number</mat-checkbox
      >
      <mat-checkbox color="primary" formControlName="date"
        >Date</mat-checkbox
      >
      <mat-checkbox color="primary" formControlName="actions"
        >Actions</mat-checkbox
      >
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
<p>{{ dynamColumns.value | json }}</p>
<div mat-dialog-actions [align]="'end'">
  <button mat-raised-button color="warn" mat-dialog-close>Close</button>
  <button
    style="margin-left: 8px"
    (click)="onSave()"
    mat-raised-button
    color="primary"
  >
    Save
  </button>
</div>
```

**ts**

```
      dynamColumns = this._formBuilder.group({
    name: false,
    telNum: false,
    date: false,
    actions: false,
  });
```

Comment: "Easy" is subjective, not definitively answerable, and opinion-based.  Please revise your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by passing data on dialog creation like this:

```
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogSettingsComponent, {
            data : {
             form: {
                name: false,
                telNum: false,
                date: false,
                actions: false,
              }
           }
        });
```

And then to DialogSettingsComponent you can access this data like this:

```
    export class DialogSettingsComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public dialogData: DialogData) {}
}
```

Then on ngOnInit of this component you can patch form value like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
     this.dynamColumns.patchValue(this.dialogData.form)

}
```

Hope so it helps!

Comment: I don't think that this solution can solve my problem. I need a checkbox to stay checked even after I close my dialog. This must not be equal to the default values stored in the form, they can also change according to what the user clicks and newly clicked checkboxes must stay checked.

Comment: After you close the modal, you can emit an event with the current checkbox selected and update object value to the parent component, then when you open dialog again you pass this object data again and you will always see last checkbox checked.